# DLL generated by LLVM (lld-link.exe) not compatible with visual studio 2017 application

Tags: visual-studio, dll, clang, llvm

**Hello, everyone,**

We’ve encountered a crash problem when using Microsoft visual studio 2017 with a dll generated by LLVM clang tools (compiled by clang-cl.exe and linked by lld-link.exe).

Our code is quite simple (just a hello world demo) so that we do not think the crash would happen. We’ve referenced to a lot of materials on internet but still could not figure it out.

**Here are the reproduce steps:**

1. Content of helloworld.h

   ```
   #include <string>
   __declspec(dllexport) void helloworld(std::string s);
   ```
2. Content of helloworld.cc

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "helloworld.h"

   void helloworld(std::string s) {
     //std::string ss = s; // uncomment this line will cause the program crash in helloworld.cc.dll, the exception points to the std::bad_alloc (allocate memory when copying the input string to the local string ss)
     //std::cout << "I am from helloworld dll, input string ss=" << ss << std::endl;
     std::cout << "I am from helloworld dll, input string size=" << s.size() << "!" << std::endl;
     std::cout << "I am from helloworld dll, input string data=" << s.data() << "!" << std::endl;
   }
   ```
3. Run the following two commands in cmd to compile and link, then the helloworld.cc.dll will be generated.

   ```
   .\build\llvm-build\Release+Asserts_Windows\bin\clang-cl.exe  /c ./helloworld.cc /Fo./helloworld.cc.obj -fms-compatibility
   .\build\llvm-build\Release+Asserts_Windows\bin\lld-link.exe "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64" /IMPLIB:./helloworld.cc.dll.lib /DLL /OUT:./helloworld.cc.dll /PDB:./helloworld.cc.dll.pdb ./helloworld.cc.obj
   ```
4. Create a helloworld console application project in vs2017 (File -> New -> Project -> visual c++ -> Windows desktop ->Console application), configure the include path, library path, dependent path in project property configuration to use helloworld.h, helloworld.cc.dll and helloworld.cc.dll.lib. here is the helloworld.cpp code:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   #include "helloworld.h"

   int main()
   {
      std::string s("abcd");
      std::cout << "I am from main, string size=" << s.size() << "!" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "I am from main, string data=" << s.data() << "!" << std::endl;
      helloworld(s);
      return 0;
   }
   ```
5. Build the project and run it in vs2017, here is the output, the string received by helloworld.cc.dll is not correct, we think this may be a compiler compatibility problem, but still could not confirm after many efforts.

   ```
   I am from main, string size=4!
   I am from main, string data=abcd!
   I am from helloworld dll, input string size=14757395258967641292!
   I am from helloworld dll, input string data=癘??!
   ```
6. Output of **.\build\llvm-build\Release+Asserts_Windows\bin\clang-cl.exe -v**

   ```
   clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
   Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
   Thread model: posix
   ```

Testing on Windows 10.

Anyone knows about the cause? Or whether it is correct to use clang and vs2017 in this way.

Comment: Are you running `clang-cl` and `lld-link` in VS2017 environment?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I was not running `clang-cl` and `lld-link` in vs2017 environment, just running in Command Line of Windows.

Comment: If you ever found a definitive answer, you may want to answer your own question. Perhaps you will get some upvotes.

Comment: 14757395258967641292 == 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.  That's not a random number when you build with MSVC++, means "not initialized".  Interop between compilers tends to work in C, rarely to never works for C++ template classes.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons I don't have VS2017 at my disposal anymore and my Clang installation also is much newer. Still, I can see a few things that are odd in your example. My tool versions are 14.34.31933 (VS2022, cl: 19.34.31937, link: 14.34.31937.0, lld-link: 15.0.1, clang-cl: 15.0.1).

### Preparations

I did not change your code, but I am using the following script from a VS2022 developer prompt configured for x64:

```
@echo off
clang-cl.exe /c ./helloworld.cc /Fo./helloworld.cc.obj -fms-compatibility
lld-link.exe /IMPLIB:./helloworld.cc.dll.lib /DLL /OUT:./helloworld.cc.dll /PDB:./helloworld.cc.dll.pdb ./helloworld.cc.obj
cl.exe /nologo /EHsc /Fe:helloworld.exe helloworld.cpp /link helloworld.cc.dll.lib
```

### Potential problems with your code

1. You hardcode `__declspec(dllexport)` in a header that is used both by the program and the DLL. Technically it shouldn't be an issue, but still ...
2. It is not clear from your question whether you are even using the same version of the STL (e.g. `std::string`), which would be necessary for an identical class layout. It could be you're using the STL version that comes with MSVC or the one from Clang, it's not evident from your question.

   - If both use the same dynamic libraries as their C/C++ runtimes, and assuming the symbols and class layouts all match, this should work, though.
   - Such a mismatch can also arise when using a Debug configuration (and C/C++ runtime) on one side and a Release one on the other ...
   - This is why generally when something allocated in one binary gets passed around, the knowledge on how to free it is passed along (similar to `IUnknown` reference counting in COM).
3. It is not clear who owns what. You are passing "by value", but in truth there is no "by value" in this case.

   - Passing the `std::string` by reference, and taking a copy, I'd expect to work ... even more so if it's a `const&`.
   - This issue is most easily sidestepped by using a C interface instead of C++, if you are crossing toolchain or language boundaries or use a common denominator the way COM does it.

### Reproducing your issue

Uncommenting those two lines in `helloworld()` of `helloworld.cc`, I get the following output and no crash:

```
>helloworld.exe
I am from main, string size=4!
I am from main, string data=abcd!
I am from helloworld dll, input string ss=abcd
I am from helloworld dll, input string size=4!
I am from helloworld dll, input string data=abcd!
```

It works. This means everything else is guesswork at this point.

Either the problem you ran into has meanwhile been fixed in Clang/LLVM, or you ran into the potential problem 2 listed above, which would be my guess.